# memory location of dictionary in python 2.6.4 only?

Tags: python

Is it possible to see a memory location/address of data dictionary in python 2.6.4 only??

Comment: seriously, it's not only about asking a question and getting the answer back. if the answer satisfies you, please accept it, so that the person who answered know he's helped someone (that's reflected in reputation points) and others know that the answer is trustworthy.

Comment: i am extremely sorry, actually i don't know i have to accept the answers. yeah its true what answer i am getting it is helping me o lot a will really thanks for all you people.  In future i will keep this concern.Sorry once again

Comment: @mukul sharma: Please read the FAQ's.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Please don't apologize or explain.  Please read and watch what others are doing.

Comment: If you don't mind can you let me know how can acknowledge my vote or accept of answers.?

Or i should write comments only? that's is also count as a acceptance of right answers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Python objects are managed by the runtime, and even if you could get the address, what would you do with it?  It sounds dangerous already.  You should ask about the problem you are trying to solve, not how you might do it.

Comment: @mukul sharma: Please read the FAQ's. Please read other questions and see what other people have done.

Answer (score 2):

In CPython use [id function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: actually i am not using cpython. there is no way to find out this in python only.?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using CPython? That's the version that most of us use. Other versions like IronPython and Jython don't have memory addresses per se, so your question doesn't make sense if you're not using CPython.

Comment: @mukul sharma: You aren't using IPython.  You aren't using Jython.  Please UPDATE your question with the first lines you get when you run "Python only"  It will say something like: `Python 2.6.3 (r263:75184, Oct  2 2009, 07:56:03) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin`.  Please update the question with information for your version of Python.  I think you *are* using CPython; but we need to see the actual response from your actual Python as an update to the question.

Comment: This is an implementation detail, and is not to be relied upon.  Any code using this would be of questionable design.

Comment: I am using Python version 2.6.4 on windows os

Comment: @mukul why don't you copy-paste the first lines you get when you run "Python only" , as S.Lott asked? and put details in question not comments